# JBOSS server log is occupying more memory in the server

Tags: java, jboss

I am running a **JSF** web application in a **JBOSS EAP server.** The application was working fine for a long time. But all of a sudden I could see that the server memory is occupied by huge amount of logs. These logs are not from the application. Please find the sample log below.

[image]

Because of this the application is not deploying again. Getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.copyStream(VFSUtils.java:439) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.copyStream(VFSUtils.java:418) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.vfs.TempDir.createFile(TempDir.java:86) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:77) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:386) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:410) [jboss-vfs-3.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.2.10.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.createResourceRoots(WarStructureDeploymentProcessor.java:171)
    ... 7 more
```

Can anyone Advice how to resolve this and why this issue is happening all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

Change Log level to "**INFO**" from "**DEBUG**"

Answer (score 1):

If you use the periodic rotating file appender write a skript to remove old log files.